Generating random numbers in MPC, but the upper bound remains secret
Suppose we are using secret sharing-based MPC over a prime-order field. Given shares of a secret integer $s$, is there a way to generate shares of uniformly random integer in $[0,s)$ such that $s$ remains secret?
Edit: The goal is to generate a random "fraction" ⋅−1
, where the denominator 
is the size of a given security parameter, and <
. It will be used as an additive mask.

Not in an information theoretic sense. When receiving a share $s_i$, you know that $s > s_i$. I'm not sure what reasonable definition of security would be achievable.

@Lev The goal is to generate a random "fraction" $r\cdot s^{-1}$, where the denominator $s$ is the size of a given security parameter, and $r<s$. It will be used as an additive mask.
